# How to pass Camera preview to the Surface created by MediaCodec.createInputSurface()?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, encoder, android-mediacodec

Ideally I'd like to accomplish two goals:

1. Pass the `Camera` preview data to a `MediaCodec` encoder via a `Surface`.  I can create the `Surface` using `MediaCodec.createInputSurface()` but the `Camera.setPreviewDisplay()` takes a `SurfaceHolder`, not a `Surface`.
2. In addition to passing the `Camera` preview data to the encoder, I'd also like to display the preview on-screen (so the user can actually see what they are encoding).  If the encoder wasn't involved then I'd use a `SurfaceView`, but that doesn't appear to work in this scenario since `SurfaceView` creates its own `Surface` and I think I need to use the one created by `MediaCodec`.

I've searched online quite a bit for a solution and haven't found one.  Some examples on [bigflake.com](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) seem like a step in the right direction but they take an approach that adds a bunch of EGL/SurfaceTexture overhead that I'd like to avoid.  I'm hoping there is a simpler example or solution where I can get the `Camera` and `MediaCodec` talking more directly without involving EGL or textures.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Android 4.3 (API 18), the [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) CameraToMpegTest approach is the correct way.

The EGL/SurfaceTexture overhead is currently unavoidable, especially for what you want to do in goal #2.  The idea is:

- Configure the Camera to send the output to a `SurfaceTexture`.  This makes the Camera output available to GLES as an "external texture".
- Render the `SurfaceTexture` to the `Surface` returned by `MediaCodec#createInputSurface()`.  That feeds the video encoder.
- Render the `SurfaceTexture` a second time, to a `GLSurfaceView`.  That puts it on the display for real-time preview.

The only data copying that happens is performed by the GLES driver, so you're doing hardware-accelerated blits, which will be fast.

The only tricky bit is you want the external texture to be available to two different EGL contexts (one for the `MediaCodec`, one for the `GLSurfaceView`).  You can see an example of creating a shared context in the "Android Breakout game recorder patch" sample on bigflake -- it renders the game twice, once to the screen, once to a `MediaCodec` encoder.

**Update:** This is implemented in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) ("Show + capture camera").

**Update:** The multi-context approach in "show + capture camera" approach is [somewhat flawed](https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/36).  The "continuous capture" Activity uses a plain SurfaceView, and is able to do both screen rendering and video recording with a single EGL context.  This is recommended.

Comment: Regarding the tricky bit, I found that the main difference between the CameraToMpegTest and the breakout game recorder was that in the recorder there's actually a shared egl context defined when creating a context for the recorder part. So just make sure the context is shared, after drawing the "main" picture, make the secondary context and surface current and then use the same drawing code again.

Comment: Alternatively, use a single EGL context with two EGL surfaces.  (Grafika has expanded quite a bit since I wrote this; see the "Continuous capture" activity for another example.)

Comment: @fadden fadden fadden.. are you the developer of the Camera2?